# number_format only if not zero

Tags: php, number-formatting

I want to show one decimal of a float if it has non zero decimals.

What is the most elegant way to do this?

```
100.00 -> 100
99.45 -> 99.5
99.44 -> 99.4
11.30 -> 11.3
2.00 -> 2
11.02 -> 11
13.05 -> 13.1
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ? Where you get stuck? Where is your code ?

Comment: @BenM default rounding is `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ini_set("precision", 8); /* low enough; eventually if needed */
var_dump((string)round($float, 1));
```

this should do the task

Comment: ini_set("precision", 8); /* low enough */
var_dump((string)round('99.45')); will output 99 not 99.5

Comment: it works, the only problem is that i have to set the precision.

Comment: Even with the default precision of 14, the examples given in the question work fine. http://codepad.viper-7.com/moZnnQ

Comment: ok if it works with default precision then your solution will be better. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

use in the following manner.

```
$x = "99.44";  // example value
$y =  number_format((float)$x, 1, '.', '');
echo str_replace(".0","",$y);
```

Comment: yes, it results in 11.3....I checked with all the above values and it works as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rounded = (!is_int($number)) ? round($number, 1) : round($number);
```

I have tested the above with your sample data and the outputs are as follows:

```
100.00 > 100
99.45 > 99.5
99.44 > 99.4
11.30 > 11.3
2.00 > 2
11.02 > 11
13.05 > 13
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this way:

`$num = 100.1;

    echo (floor($num) == $num) ? $num : number_format($num,1);`

Comment: not really. $num = 2.00 returns 2.00, your example returns 100.0

Comment: Are you sure? I've tested this with the examples you gave in your original post, and the answers match up exactly.

Comment: @user352891 using for example $num = 1000.12 adds a comma between the 1 and the 0... Not what he asked?